# Can a Chrome extension safely inject content scripts into *sandboxed* iframes?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to study how websites use a particular Web API by using a Chrome extension that replaces the API with a shim. In the extension's manifest, I set up a content script that is injected into all URLs, including frames, including about:blank and other frames with weird origins:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true,
      "match_origin_as_fallback": true,
      "match_about_blank": true,
      "world": "MAIN"
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

This works great as far as injecting the code goes, but I noticed that when a page has an iframe with the `sandbox` attribute enabled (e.g. `<iframe id="my-iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>`), the script is injected but does not run. Instead, I get this error:

> Blocked script execution in 'about:blank' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

This all makes sense to me in terms of what `sandbox` is supposed to do but is obviously frustrating insofar as it is preventing my extension from working in this case (even though scripts cannot execute in the iframe, scripts in the parent frame can reach into the iframe and access Web APIs from inside it, bypassing my extension).

Obviously one thing I could do is write another content script that will add `allow-scripts` to the `sandbox` attribute of any iframe that I see, but that seems like a bad idea for websites that actually rely on sandboxed iframes to sandbox untrusted markup. Is there another way I can allow *only* my injected content script, but not other scripts, to run inside sandboxed iframes?

Comment: Definitely a bug. You can report it in https://crbug.com.